# Paired t-test, Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test and chisquare test. Which test should I choose?

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I observed moth oviposition in orchard for 4 moths (400 clusters per week). The moth oviposit on leaf and apple. I want to compare the means between oviposit on leaf and apple. I suppose to use paired t-test, however, the result of shapiro.test showed my data do not fit normality. I was wondering if I should use  Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test for this case?

Moreover, I did some treatment on apples to prevent the ovipostion. I observed eggs on treated and untreated clusters weekly (treated and untreated apple trees were in the same orchard). Then I got a table like:

```
               Treated  untreated
Egg Observed       40       1852
Non-observed     6000      12600
```

Can I use a chisquare test in this case?

Answer (score 3):

If your data are paired (as they seem to be, since you are supposed to use paired t-tests) the Kruskal Wallis is not appropriate as it is for independent data. I think a Friedman test is better suited to your question (see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test))

On the table - you certainly *can* use chi-square here, but since you have a dependent variable (egg observed) and an independent variable (treatment) it might be better to use logistic regression. But, it appears that your data are not independent since the trees were in clusters; therefore, a nonlinear mixed model might be even better (if trees in clusters are likely to be similar, as seems likely); there are also other methods for dealing with clustered samples

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read the link you provided. I also googled for more information. However, I found that Friedman test is suitable for data in 3 groups or more than 3 groups. The code for R is in this way: friedman.test(y, ...).                        

## Default S3 method:
friedman.test(y, groups, blocks, ...)

## S3 method for class 'formula'
friedman.test(formula, data, subset, na.action, ...)        However, my data was only in 2 groups ( ovipostion on leaf and oviposition on apple). I was wondering how can I use Friedman test in this case?

Comment: In your second paragraph, you suggested that it might be better to use logistic regression. My task was count the times of moth ovipostion on treated apple and untreated apple trees(number of eggs), I considered Poisson Regression might be a better choice. As I metioned treated and untreated trees were in the same orchard. Therefore, my data are not independent. You said: nonlinear mixed model might be even better. I checked The R Book. I found there were dozens of methods, How can I know which one is suitable?

Comment: @jack, Friedman test ia a valid test 2+ paired samples. With 2 samples, it gives results very close to those obtained by **sign test**, so you may use this. (The latter is a little bit more liberal, in normal approximation regime.)

Comment: @jackWei choosing among different nlme is a huge job.

Comment: @ttnphns thank you for your suggestion. I will be able to use friedman test once I put my data into matrix. As the sign test you metioned, I do not considered it is proper test. Becasuse oviposit on leaf and apple are dependent events. If moth lay more eggs on leaf, obviously, there will be less eggs on apple.

Comment: @jackWei Why do you think that "more eggs on leaf" $\implies$ "fewer eggs on apple" would invalidate the sign test? Conditioning on the total sample size, as is done in the sign test, more in one category necessarily implies fewer of the other. I don't see the problem at all.

Comment: @ttnphns, you also metioned the latter is a bit more liberal,in normal approximation regime.However, Peter Flom pointed out that my data are not independent, since the trees were in same orchard. I note that you suggested binomial test in another case. Is it suitable in my case?

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your reply. I tried sign test. However the result is very different from friedman test. The result of sign test implied moth oviposite more egg on leaf. The result of friedman test implied there is no significant difference between moth oviposite on leaf and apple. However, ttnphns said:The result of friedman test is very close to those obtained by sign test, Something must be wrong.